# Compare String with "like" against a list

Tags: sql, wildcard, sql-like

is it possible to compare a string against a list using "like" and wildcards, so sth like

```
select column 
from table
where column like('%foo%', '%bar%')
```

The example does not work in any database format I know. How can I do this without using a verbose solution like

```
select column 
from table
where column like'%foo%' or column like '%bar%'
```

I am interested in a platform-independent solution but mainly Sybase ASE.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Your second solution is not only the way to go, it IS also platform independent. It's ANSI-SQL standard of 1992, more than 22 years old.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/CACGCGGC.htm) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL/PostgreSQL you could use regexp, that is one way.

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE (column REGEXP '^ALA[0-9]')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp
http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/databases/2006/02/02/postgresq_regexes.html

Second solution would be, mentioned by you creating many likes, joined by or.

Comment: I think all databases support regular expressions, they only differ in notation.